# How can I install one Web Application in two context roots in Weblogic 10g?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

How can I install one Web Application in two context roots in Weblogic 10g?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a packaging issue. Package the WAR twice, each with a specific `WEB-INF/weblogic.xml`, to solve it. 
For the first WAR:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-web-app>
  <context-root>my-context-1</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

For the second WAR:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-web-app>
  <context-root>my-context-2</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

This will allow you to use standard deployment tools. I don't recommend installing your application as a shared library.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need this, I recommend making your application a shared library and creating just a new web.xml file to change the context root for the two deployments.

This way you won't duplicate the entire war file and you still can configure them individually.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an Apache reverse proxy in front of the app server, you could use mod_rewrite to change the context root on-the-fly on the server side (transparent for the client).
For example: adding the iinstructions below to httpd.conf will return the content of 2.html when the client calls 1.html:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/1.html$ /2.html
```

Respectivly, you could make the obvious translation to translate the second context root to the other single context root.